# SQL to get order items straight from the database?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, orders

How do we get a list of order items and their data (name, sku, quantity, price, weight, and dimensions)? Without using Magento's own framework components.

The problem is if the order contains 5 products I would get maybe 7 items from querying the table. This is caused by the different product types (simple, group, voucher, configurable, etc.) and different product ids so cannot be combined.

```
$items = array();

$sql = (
  "SELECT oi.name, oi.sku, oi.qty_ordered, oi.price, oi.weight
  FROM {$db->prefix}sales_flat_order_item oi
  WHERE oi.order_id = ". (int)$order_entity_id .";"
);

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $items[] = [
      'name'                   => $row['name'],
      'sku'                    => $row['sku'],
      'quantity'               => (float)$row['qty_ordered'],
      'unit_price'             => (float)$row['price'],
      'unit_weight'            => (float)$row['weight'],
      //'unit_length'            => (float)$row['length'], // Not present?
      //'unit_width'             => (float)$row['width'], // Not present?
      //'unit_height'            => (float)$row['height'], // Not present?
    ];
  }

  $result->close();
}
```

If I pass a filter AND `product_type = 'simple'` to get only the simple products, they do not contain price.

Comment: Have you tried using "JOIN" query?

Comment: Have you got the solution ? If not the i have it.

Comment: No not yet. I think a little PHP logic could be needed to distinguish simple products from configurable+simple products. It's like configurable snd group are parents of the sinple items. But price weight etc is a bit spread over them. One holds this, the other holds that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the configuration setting for `Catalog->Frontend->Use Flat Catalog Product` set to `ON`, you can join the `sales_flat_order_item` table to `catalog_product_flat_[#]`.  If you only have one (catalog_product_flat_1), that is fairly easy, but it can still be done with more if you use a [Union](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

For one flat product table:

```
SELECT 
    oi.name, 
    oi.sku, 
    oi.qty_ordered, 
    oi.price, 
    oi.weight, 
    flat.width, 
    flat.height, 
    flat.length
FROM sales_flat_order_item oi
join catalog_product_flat_1 flat
on oi.product_id = flat.entity_id
WHERE oi.order_id = <order_id>;
```

For multiple flat product tables:

```
SELECT 
    oi.name, 
    oi.sku, 
    oi.qty_ordered, 
    oi.price, 
    oi.weight, 
    flat.width, 
    flat.height, 
    flat.length
FROM sales_flat_order_item oi
JOIN (
    select entity_id, width, height, length from catalog_product_flat_1
UNION DISTINCT
    select entity_id, width, height, length from catalog_product_flat_2
/*
REPEAT 2 LINES ABOVE FOR catalog_product_flat_3, catalog_product_flat_4, etc
*/
) flat
on oi.product_id = flat.entity_id
WHERE oi.order_id = <order_id>;
```

**EDIT**

This will accomplish the same goal regardless of whether you are using flat product tables:

```
SELECT 
    oi.name, 
    oi.sku, 
    oi.qty_ordered, 
    oi.price, 
    oi.weight,
    w.value 'width',
    h.value 'height',
    l.value 'length'
FROM sales_flat_order_item oi
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal w
ON oi.product_id = w.entity_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal h
ON oi.product_id = h.entity_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal l
ON oi.product_id = l.entity_id
WHERE oi.order_id = <order_id>
AND w.attribute_id = (
    select attribute_id from eav_attribute 
    where entity_type_id = 4 
    and attribute_code = 'width'
)
AND h.attribute_id = (
    select attribute_id from eav_attribute 
    where entity_type_id = 4 
    and attribute_code = 'height'
)
AND l.attribute_id = (
    select attribute_id from eav_attribute 
    where entity_type_id = 4 
    and attribute_code = 'length'
);
```

Comment: Thank for your efforts trying. How will this distinguish what is a simple product or simple+configurable? Where it occurs multiple times in the table.

Comment: @tim these should all be specific to the actual item used, but yes, the configurable and simple product will both be listed.  If you want the child-product's sku and dimensions **as configured** simply add `AND oi.product_type <> 'configurable'` to any of these.  If you prefer to see the parent-product, add `AND oi.parent_item_id is null`.  If this solves it for you, let me know which one and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

how about with this query, I try joined your query with `catalog_product_entity` and `catalog_product_index_price` tables, so you will get all products with contain price :

```
SELECT DISTINCT oi.name, oi.sku, oi.qty_ordered, oi.weight,  
`idx_price`.`price`
FROM sales_flat_order_item AS oi 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON oi.sku = cpe.sku   
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `idx_price` ON idx_price.entity_id = cpe.entity_id 
 WHERE oi.order_id = <order_id>
```

then you can add the `product_type` filtering on the end query like this :

```
AND oi.product_type = 'configurable'
```

or

```
AND oi.product_type = 'simple'
```

hope this can help

Comment: Price is already present in sales_flat_order_item.price so I would be asking for trouble if I grab that from the products table. The only thing I can't find in sales_flat_order_item are dimensions.

Comment: yes you will get trouble if your product included in catalog promotions or customer using voucher discount,  it will cause actual price in the `sales_flat_order_item` will be different with `catalog_product_index_price`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  SELECT  
>         CONCAT(address.firstname,' ',
>         address.lastname) AS Name,
>         address.email AS Email,
>         items.created_at AS Date,
>         items.name AS Description,
>         items.store_id AS Logon,
>         items.name AS Category,
>         items.store_id AS FeedbackDate,              
>         items.sku AS ProductSearchcode,
>         items.order_id AS Orderref  
>  FROM sales_flat_order AS orders
>   JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
>   ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
>   LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address
>   ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id
> WHERE    
>   items .created_at BETWEEN  '2014-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-30 
>   00:00:00' AND orders.status = 'complete'
> ```

Also you can add AND orders.status in ('processing', 'complete') depending upon your requirement.

Comment: I think you confused Item Name with customer name. This doesn't sort out the problem where a simple product also is present in a group or configurable product, so there will be duplicate rows for the same item. I just need to acess sales_flar_order_item and extract the items without dupes.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, use group by will give you your results:

```
    "SELECT oi.name, oi.sku, oi.qty_ordered, oi.price, oi.weight
  FROM sales_flat_order_item oi
  WHERE oi.order_id = ". (int)$order_entity_id . " group by sku ;"
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[image]

Comment: And how will they be grouped when the price is in configurable but the quantity in simple. See the product_type column.

Comment: price and qty always be in configurable. if 2qty selected for any of child product. 2 will also the configurable quantity., and present in above query. look at above image attached.
Let me know if you still have any questions

Comment: I case of simple product added as stand alone product  this will work properly as well. in that case price & qty will be for that simple product.